# Hotels Combined Error loading files

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I am using a search box from hotel combined but the thing is that I have errors in the console.
Here is the code provided from Hotel combined:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
</head>
<body>
<div width="700px" height="700px">
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.hotelscombined.com/SearchBox/317607'></script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the errors

```
GET file://www.hotelscombined.com/Script/JsMapper.ashx?key=/areas/searchbox.js&cdn=1.0.2015.356005-C79066 net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUNDHCSB.loadScript @ 317607:66HCSB.loadResources @ 317607:193HCSB.buildSB @ 317607:131(anonymous function) @ 317607:206(anonymous function) @ 317607:211
317607:32 GET file://www.hotelscombined.com/areas/affiliate/content/hc_searchbox.css?cdn=1.0.2015.356005-C79066 net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUNDHCSB.loadCSS @ 317607:32HCSB.loadResources @ 317607:194HCSB.buildSB @ 317607:131(anonymous function) @ 317607:206(anonymous function) @ 317607:211
www.hotelscombined.com/content/images/searchboxes/whitelabel/poweredby_hotelscombined.png?cdn=1.0.2015.356005-C79066:1 GET file://www.hotelscombined.com/content/images/searchboxes/whitelabel/poweredby_hotelscombined.png?cdn=1.0.2015.356005-C79066 net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

Comment: is the link of js an API? And if it is please post the link. How did you found the js source?

Comment: Here is the link http://www.hotelscombined.com/SearchBox/317607             the link is given by hotel combined api system

Comment: I don't mean the link you use in your js. I want the stite page that offer the link.

Comment: https://affiliates.hotelscombined.com/
Register then you will find Search box under Affiliate links then create a search and they give you the code